# Can't access protected property of Doctrine 2 entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity in doctrine 2 that has the following property

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="space_data", type="json_array", nullable=true)
 */
protected $_spaceData = [];
```

I'm saving and retrieving this field ok. When I dump this entity is populated alright, like this:

```
#_spaceData: array:22 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Centro Cultural Niemeyer"
    "location" => array:2 [▶]
    "endereco" => null
    "En_CEP" => null
    "En_Nome_Logradouro" => null
    "En_Num" => null
    "En_Complemento" => null
    "En_Bairro" => null
    "En_Municipio" => null
    "En_Estado" => null
    "telefone1" => "(66) 8877-4411"
    "telefone2" => null
    "telefonePublico" => "(99) 6688-5544"
    "emailPrivado" => "acc@gmail.com"
    "emailPublico" => "acc@gmail.com"
    "acessibilidade" => "Sim"
    "acessibilidade_fisica" => "Banheiros adaptados;Elevador;Rampa de acesso"
    "site" => "http://www.centroculturalniemeyer.com.br"
    "googleplus" => null
    "facebook" => null
    "twitter" => null
  ]
```

but when I try to access it in the code using

```
$entity->_spaceData
```

It is returning null. I'm not well versed in Doc2 and I'm currently maintaining a project here. How is it possible to be dumping the right values but when I try to access it returns null? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: yeah, I thought this. But how can I access other protected methods without problem?

Comment: You aren't.  Either the properties are public or they are "virtual" properties accessed vi a magical __get function.  If you think otherwise then you are misunderstanding the code.

Comment: Tnx man, you nailed. I set a getter and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For the completness sake I created the answer with the example.

In OOP you can't access private and protected fields. In order to access them in your entity you should use public `getters` and `getters`.

```
<?php
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="space_data", type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $_spaceData = [];

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSpaceData() {
        return $this->_spaceData;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $spaceData
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSpaceData($spaceData) {
        $this->_spaceData = $spaceData;
        return $this;
    }
}
```